# AWS XRAY fails on segment close with RangeError: Invalid string length

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-xray

XRAY fails to stringify due too most likely too big object. Not sure how I should approach in such case. Any help?

Using aws-xray-sdk-core 3.5.3

```
/node_modules/aws-xray-sdk-core/dist/lib/segments/segment.js:345
return JSON.stringify(object !== null && object !== void 0 ? object : this, SegmentUtils.getJsonStringifyReplacer());
^
RangeError: Invalid string length
at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
at Segment2.serialize (/node_modules/aws-xray-sdk-core/dist/lib/segments/segment.js:345:17)
at Segment2.format (/node_modules/aws-xray-sdk-core/dist/lib/segments/segment.js:339:17)
at Object.send (/node_modules/aws-xray-sdk-core/dist/lib/segment_emitter.js:117:33)
at Segment2.flush (/node_modules/aws-xray-sdk-core/dist/lib/segments/segment.js:330:24)
at Segment2.Segment2.close (/node_modules/aws-xray-sdk-core/dist/lib/segments/segment.js:320:14)
at <anonymous> (/ecs-runtime.ts:29:15)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at startRuntime (/ecs-runtime.ts:12:18)
```